# Image tag disappears when adding link using Bootstrap Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give the user the flexiblity to add/edit a url to an image using Bootstrap editable, which is commonly used for inline text editing. I added an image tag between the anchor tags and this works perfectly well except that when the user adds a link, the image becomes hidden/invisible. When the page is refreshed, the image reappears and the link is saved in the backend. I noticed that after editing, the image tag in the Html code is not present.

I wanted to know what am I missing here. Codes:

```
        <HTML>      

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="{{user.facebook}}" id="linkedin" data-type="text" data-url="{{ url_for('account.AccountView:editFacebook') }}" data-pk="{{user.id}}"  data-title="Change your Facebook profile url" ><img id="facebooklogo" width="200" height = "70" class="img img-rounded" src="/static/logos/facebook.jpg"></img></a>                              
        </div>

        <Jquery>

        <link href="/static/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        $('#facebook').editable({
        placement:"right",
        error: function (errors) {
        }

        });

        <script src="/static/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. All one needs to is to add this code :

```
        $('#facebook').editable({
        placement:"right",
        error: function (errors) {
        },
        display: function(value, response) {
        $(this).html('<img src="logos/facebooklogo.jpg">');
        }

        });

        instead of just

        $('#facebook').editable({
        placement:"right",
        error: function (errors) {
        }

        });
```

and it worked.